# Blocking Google Analytics cookies by country

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

When using this as part of the Google Analytics script to block cookies for EU visitors prior to consent

```js
  gtag('consent', 'default', {
                'ad_storage': 'denied',
                'analytics_storage': 'denied'
                'region': ['BE', 'BG', 'CZ', 'DK', 'DE', 'EE', 'IE', 'GR', 'ES', 'FR', 'HR', 'IT', 'CY', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'HU', 'MT', 'NL', 'AT', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SI', 'SK', 'FI', 'SE']
                });
```

Do I have to use the 'region': ['BE', 'BG', 'CZ', 'DK', 'DE', 'EE', 'IE', 'GR', 'ES', 'FR', 'HR', 'IT', 'CY', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'HU', 'MT', 'NL', 'AT', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SI', 'SK', 'FI', 'SE'] part here as well?

```js
gtag('consent', 'update', {
      'ad_storage': 'granted',
      'analytics_storage': 'granted',
      'region': ['BE', 'BG', 'CZ', 'DK', 'DE', 'EE', 'IE', 'GR', 'ES', 'FR', 'HR', 'IT', 'CY', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'HU', 'MT', 'NL', 'AT', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SI', 'SK', 'FI', 'SE']

    })
```

Is there a shorter way to specify all EU countries?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such country as EU - it is reserved by ISO for European union

https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Glossary:Country_codes

Also this might help https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/consent

Comment: Thanks! So then using  'region': ['BE', 'BG', 'CZ', 'DK', 'DE', 'EE', 'IE', 'GR', 'ES', 'FR', 'HR', 'IT', 'CY', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'HU', 'MT', 'NL', 'AT', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SI', 'SK', 'FI', 'SE']  is the correct and only option, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, there is no ISO code for "All European countries".

Comment: Thanks! So then the question remains, should 'region': ['BE', 'BG', 'CZ', 'DK', 'DE', 'EE', 'IE', 'GR', 'ES', 'FR', 'HR', 'IT', 'CY', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'HU', 'MT', 'NL', 'AT', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SI', 'SK', 'FI', 'SE'] be used in both places (denied and granted code) or just in the denied code?

Comment: Just in denied, you deny on some regions, and when user decides to allow it - you update the consent to granted, I don't think gtag will consider region field there.
You can read more here https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/consent